# Is it possible to bounce an image with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i trying to bounce a jpg with jquery but its not going anywhere you can check the code at

http://jsfiddle.net/sethportman/WZumy/6/

Answer (score 2):

Some problems:

```
$("document").load(function(){
```

should be

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

and

```
$(this).effect('bounce',1000 )
```

should be

```
$(this).effect('bounce', {}, 1000)
```

and beyond this, you are not loading the UI/Effects plugins, so your particular page doesn't have a `.effect()` method available.

Answer (score 2):

You have to include jQuery UI for the effect, and be sure that jQuery has loaded properly:
http://jsfiddle.net/WZumy/11/

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/WZumy/12/

As posted, you will want to ensure you have loaded the library correctly (in JSFiddle) and ensure you wait for the DOM to load `$(document).ready`

Answer (score 0):

dont know if you ever had this answered. but here is a fixed fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/WZumy/17/